# POST array from angular to php

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, json

I am posting an array from angular to PHP. The array i sent is like that [92,70,86,62,75,84,95]
but in php it's turned into like this - "[92,70,86,62,75,84,95]".

### **My expected output from php is**

{
 user_id: false,
 data: [92,70,86,62,75,84,95]
}
**The output i am getting is**
{
 user_id: false,
 data: "[92,70,86,62,75,84,95]"
}

## The code for posting data from angular is

```
$scope.data = [92,70,86,62,75,84,95];
 $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'http://localhost/learn_php/api/api_set_data/',
         data: $scope.data,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        });
```

## The code in php is

```
public function api_set_data(){

    $array['user_id']  = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $array['data'] =  file_get_contents("php://input");

    $serializedData = serialize($array);
    file_put_contents(APPPATH."assets/get_values.txt", $serializedData);

    echo json_encode($array);        
  }
```

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not capable of any complex structures, only key-value string pairs. Consider using `application/json` instead. Either way, you need to `json_decode()` the result of `file_get_contents()` in your PHP code.

Comment: but it shows the following error
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/learn_php/api/api_set_data/. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: So configure your "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" in server side

Comment: @UsamaIshaque You should get that error either way. That indicates that the form is being served from something other than localhost.

Comment: solved header issue as well as used json_decode instead of json_encode but still getting the same output like this 
{
 user_id: false,
 data: "[73,66,75,70,94,100,60,89,69,79]"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify and json_decode respectively

**Javascript**

```
data: JSON.stringify($scope.data)
```

**PHP**

```
$array['data'] =  json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```